# Trigonometric equation of the form $(a \sin(x) + b \cos(x) ) (k a \sin(x) + k b \cos(x) + c) = \sin(z)$

Tags: trigonometry

I have to find the solution for the following trigonometric equation

$(a \sin(x) + b \cos(x) ) (k a \sin(x) + k b \cos(x) + c) = \sin(x)$

where $a,b,c,k$ are all real constants.

Anyone who can provide any help/hint?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**

Take $d=\sqrt{a^2+b^2}$ and divide the equation by $d$:

$$\left[ \frac{a}{d}\sin x + \frac{b}{d}\cos x\right]\left[ k\frac{a}{d}\sin x + k\frac{b}{d}\cos x+\frac{c}{d}\right]=\frac{1}{d}\sin x $$

Let's call $a/d=\cos y$ and then $b/d = \sin y$

$$\left[ \sin x \cos y+ \sin y\cos x\right]\left[ k\sin x \cos y  + k\sin y\cos x+\frac{c}{d}\right]=\frac{1}{d}\sin x $$

$$\sin (x+y)\left[ k\sin(x+y)+\frac{c}{d}\right]=\frac{1}{d}\sin x $$